# python - extract rows before and after a particular value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Code event date
1 A 01/01/2023
1 X 01/02/2023
1 B 01/03/2023
1 C 01/04/2023
2 C 01/01/2023
2 C 01/02/2023
2 X 01/03/2023
2 A 01/04/2023
2 B 01/05/2023
2 A 01/05/2023
2 C 01/06/2023
3 A 01/01/2023
3 S 01/02/2023
4 X 01/01/2023
4 A 01/02/2023
4 B 01/03/2023"""), sep = " ")
```

I need the events that occured before and after event = 'X' as below:

[image]

I tried below but it is not working:

```py
df_t.sort_values(['code', 'date'], inplace=True)
df_t.code = df_t.code.astype('category')
df_t['X_index'] = df_t['event'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'X' else 0)
df_t['Before_X'] = df_t['X_index'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[4] == 1 else 0, raw=True)
df_t['After_X'] = df_t['X_index'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[4] if x[0] == 1 else 0, raw=True)
trial = df_t.groupby('Code').apply(lambda x: x[(x['Before_X'] == 1) | (x['After_X'] == 1)])
```

but I am not getting desired result. Please help.

Comment: Please provide sample data as text, not image - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example